# product show in stock in admin order when it is in out of stock Magento

Tags: magento, zend-framework, admin, status

Hi i am trapped in a very **strange** situation, my client has **enable** the customers to order the products which are **out of stock** , the problem is when the customer **place** the order it shows the product in stock in order . I need to show the product status out of stock in the order so he come to know about the order item status .
Below is the settings i have in **catalog-> inventory** in admin
[image]

please suggest me where i am doing mistake or how can i do this

thanks

Comment: Does it need to be reindexed? Some more details on your Magento version would be good.

Comment: i am using the magento 1.7.02

Answer (score -1):

You need to modify your product.phtml inside app/design/frontend/{yourpackage}/{yourtheme}/template/catalog/product/view.phtml

Add following in your code scope for testing and checking if its not already showing out of stock .

```
$stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item');
$resource = $stockItem->loadByProduct($_product->getId());
if(round($resource->getQty(),0) < 1)
{
   echo "product is out of stock";
}
```

The above code actually tests if there is any quantity available in stock and is greater than 1. Also make a note that this will not work for the products setup as not to be managed by stock under inventory tab in product add/modify case.

Thanks